# Can I control the 'reinforcements needed' list? How else can I get reinforcements where I need them?

Tags: planetside-2

I was leading Charlie squad. We just took Dahaka Amp station.The rest of the platoon was defending Mao Tech Plant, or otherwise fighting enemy factions around that area.

2 enemy platoons arrived at Dahaka, in a couple of galaxies and a few sunderers, plus tanks and MAXes. We had no time to repair all the turrets, nor did we have enough manpower to defend the generators. After a hard fight, we eventually lost. Delta squad wanted to come, but they were already tied up. No chance of Alpha coming and Bravo was just 3 guys. By the time Delta they finished their fight and got in a galaxy, we were already beyond repair at Dahaka.

If I could control the 'reinforcements needed' screen, many more free members of the faction, along with many Delta squad, could have simply spawned in the main spawn room. Our squad was good, we just needed more cannon fodder and distractions.

So, is there a way to control the 3 spawn areas appearing in the 'reinforcements list' for the faction, when deploying? If this is not possible, what other ways did I miss in trying to get Delta to the party?

Answer (score 5):

You can not control the "reinforcements needed" tab, it is fully automatical and the algorithm is not known.

However, as squad leader you can get access to the [command chat](http://wiki.planetside-universe.com/ps/Command_Comm_Channel) for 100 certs. In command chat you can talk to all other squad leaders on all continents and request reinforcements that way. Default key is **Numpad7** for the voice chat and **/leader** for the text chat. If you certed into this channel, you can also use **/orders** to send a message to all players on the continent, though i strongly recommend not abusing this for any other purpose than requesting assistance. You can get banned if you use it for outfit or squad recruiting. You also will become the laughing stock of your server if you use */orders* to ask people to go to the crown.

You can also cert into [Request Reinforcements](http://wiki.planetside-universe.com/ps/Request_Reinforcements), which allows you to set markers on the map. While they don't have any direct effect, other players will see them and might respond.